# get API in spring boot with one to many relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two models that are having one to many relation (customers have many invoices)
so i  create one - many relation on it, this is my **customer class** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private long serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;


    @OneToMany
    private Set <Invoice> invoices;
}
```

and this is **invoices class** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private long serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

and then i create GET API ( get customers ) but it's nor working and return this error :

**nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.invoices.model.Customer["invoices"]), path=/customer/viewList}]**

and this is my api :

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    List<Customer> customers =  cutomerRepository.findAll();
    return customers;
}
```

and **controller** :

```
   @GetMapping("/viewList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers() {
            List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            customers = customerService.getAllCustomers();
            if (customers.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a Bidirectional relation and therefore an endless loop if json tries to deserialize the Object.

You can use `@JsonIgnore` to break the loop or use DTOs to return at the endpoint

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private long serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

DTO would look something like this (I like to use records for this but since I don't know if you use Java 17 I still use class):

Customer:

```java
@Data
public class CustomerDTO {
    private final int id;
    private final long serialNumber;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final String mobileNumber;
    private final boolean isDeleted;

    private final Set <Invoice> invoices;

    public static CustomerDTO fromModel(Customer customer) {
        return new CustomerDTO(
            customer.getId(),
            customer.getSerialNumber(),
            customer.getFirstName(),
            customer.getLastName(),
            customer.getEmail(),
            customer.getMobileNumber(),
            customer.isDeleted(),
            customer.getInvoices()
                    .stream()
                    .map(InvoiceDTO::fromModel)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        );
    }
}
```

Invoice (here you don't show the customer again):

```java
@Data
public class InvoiceDTO {
    private final int id;
    private final String status;
    private final Timestamp createdDate;
    private final boolean isDeleted;

    public static InvoiceDTO fromModel(Invoice invoice) {
        return new InvoiceDTO(
            invoice.getId(),
            invoice.getStatus(),
            invoice.getCreatedDate(),
            invoice.isDeleted()
        );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/viewList")
public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerDTO>> getAllCustomers() {
   List<CustomerDTO> customers = new ArrayList<>();
   customers = customerService.getAllCustomers()
                              .stream()
                              .map(CustomerDTO::fromModel)
                              .toList() //Depending on Java Version .collect(Collectors.toList());
   if (customers.isEmpty()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
   }
   return new ResponseEntity<>(customers., HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: how can i use dto on it  ?

Comment: JsonIgnore not working, sam error

Comment: I edited my answer with an example for DTO

Comment: ok, i write the dto, but still, how can i solve the issue ?

Comment: This should hopefully solve the issue because you break the loop with the DTOs since you don't have customer in Invoice again. They give you more control over what you return.

Comment: so how the api will look like ?

Comment: I added static from classes in the DTOs which are responsible to convert your model into the DTO. Now you would just use them to convert the model objects you get from the service

Comment: last question `fromModel` not working why ?

Comment: I work with java 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245926/discussion-between-ausgefuchster-and-renad-sahal).

Answer (score 0):

Do not open the entity class directly to the outside world

As DTO use for example:

```java
public class InvoiceDTO {

    private int id;
    private long serialNumber;
    private String status;
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private CustomerDTO customer;
}
```

See it applied in my GitHub repo [FurnitureStoreApplication, example DTO classes in package `dto`](https://github.com/musanabiyev/FurnitureStoreApplication/tree/main/src/main/java/com/company/dto):

Comment: but still, how can i solve the problem ?

Comment: check it out
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer", referencedColumnName = "id")